# Better way of saying "in order to demonstrate this"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

What is a better way of saying "in order to demonstrate this, I will..."? I already use "to that effect" in the same paragraph. I'm looking for something as compact and concise as "to that effect" that will also be a good transition for the beginning of a new paragraph.

Comment: Can you give a little more context? As an example sentence of the thing that's being demonstrated, is it a contended point of fact, something someone believe's etc?

Comment: Requests to help rephrase a sentence, phrase, or single word are off-topic for us, but okay for English. I've asked the mods to migrate this question there.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "To illustrate this, I will...", "Demonstrating this, I will..."  or "As an example,.."

Answer (score 2):

I would sometimes use "to this end", however that is also more a general term. Something like: "We wish to show that space whales are secretly communicating with us. To this end, we will monitor the frequencies determined to be most likely to carry space whale song."

Answer (score 1):

Is the sentence in question immediately followed by the character actually performing the demonstration?  In that case:

"Observe."
(Does thing).

However, the whole thought "in order to demonstrate this, I will..." might be completely unnecessary. If the character already talked about the thing, just having them do the thing should save words.

Answer (score 0):

Is it appropriate to use "Therefore"?

Answer (score 0):

"I'll show this (is true, is so, isn't so) by. . .